# Can't start tests in selenium project in Docker

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile

```
 Project:
       - src
       - suites
       - pom.xml
       - Dockerfile
```

```
        FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim
        RUN     mkdir /app
        WORKDIR /app
        COPY    pom.xml .
        COPY    suites .
        COPY    src .
        RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
        CMD ["mvn","test"]
```

[POM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RNzf.png)

Build success.
But when I try to run I get:

```
 - [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test
   (default-test) on project Dashboard_autotests: There are test
   failures. 
 - [ERROR] [ERROR] Please refer to
   /app/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
 - [ERROR]
   Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump,
   [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
 - [ERROR] There was an
   error in the forked process 
 - [ERROR] Suite file /app/suites/ui.xml is
   not a valid file
 - [ERROR]
   org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There
   was an error in the forked process 
 - [ERROR] Suite file
   /app/suites/ui.xml is not a valid file
 - [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:656)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105) [ERROR] 
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956) [ERROR]  
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288) [ERROR]   
   at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192) [ERROR]     
   at
   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
   Method) [ERROR]         at
   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   [ERROR]         at
   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   [ERROR]         at
   java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) [ERROR]   
   at
   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
   [ERROR]         at
   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

Comment: `[ERROR] Suite file /app/suites/ui.xml is not a valid file` this is giving some hint that it's now able to find some xml files, also have you installed selenium drivers in the container?

Comment: I'm using webdrivermanager. 
So, I agree that main problem is "[ERROR] Suite file /app/suites/ui.xml is not a valid file"
But I can understand what is the cause.

Comment: can you hop inside the container by removing the last line of `Dockerfile` and checking if the desired file has been copied properly?

Comment: Thanks. Got it. 

```   RUN     mkdir /app
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY    pom.xml .
    ADD     suites ./suites
    ADD     src ./src
    RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true```
Now it works

Comment: Awesome, please answer your question with the fix and the root cause and close it. So that others... when they have the same problem can refer it. 

Answer (score 0):

Correct Docketfile

```
FROM maven:3.6.0-jdk-11-slim
RUN     mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY    pom.xml .
ADD     suites ./suites
ADD     src ./src
COPY    start.sh .
RUN mvn -f pom.xml clean package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
CMD ["mvn","test","-Denv=dev"]
```